How to make a soft-delete Many to Many relationship in Adonis.js?
My business case is for an online store

Items can be put into orders. Each item can be only in one active order at a time.
When order is cancelled, all the items return to available stock.
I'd like to keep track of which items were in the cancelled order.

This seems to me like a place for a item_id, order_id pivot table, that has soft delete deleted_at property.
How do I make this work in Adonis.js? The @manyToMany relationship seems to automatically skip over the properties of the pivot table, so I don't know how to filter for deleted_at=null. How can I do the soft delete with @manyToMany?

I have something like this in my Items model
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Items::class, 'item_orders', 'item_id', 'order_id')
            ->wherePivotNull('deleted_at'); // It is necessary to remove softdeletes in belongsToMany
    }

